# Postgres window function calculations based on sets of two

Tags: postgresql, dense-rank

I am having difficulties with what should be a simple query using window function. My problem comes from the fact that I need the 2nd row as part of the equation.

Here is my basic select * From table events.

```
  id   |          type          | event_id | event_user |     event_time                                                                                                                                                                                   
-------+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------------                                                                                                                                                                             
 42047 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 06:25:03                                                                                                                                                                              
 42046 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 06:25:17                                                                                                                                                                              
 42042 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 06:57:00                                                                                                                                                                              
 42043 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 08:20:00                                                                                                                                                                              
 42045 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 08:34:54                                                                                                                                                                              
 42044 | flex2                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 08:38:02
```

My objective is to get the time difference between two events where the next event is the first one after the previous event. Like so ....

```
  id   |          type          | event_id | event_user |     event_time                                                                                                                                                                                   
-------+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------------                                                                                                                                                                             
 42047 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 06:25:03                                                                                                                                                                              
 42046 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 06:25:17                                                                                                                                                                              

-- Need difference between event_time of (id 42046) and event_time of (id 42047)                                                                                                                                                                           

 42042 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 06:57:00                                                                                                                                                                              
 42043 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 08:20:00                                                                                                                                                                              


-- Need difference between event_time of (id 42043) and event_time of (id 42042)                                                                                                                                                                           

 42045 | flex1                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 08:34:54                                                                                                                                                                              
 42044 | flex2                  |     4742 |          8 | 2018-04-29 08:38:02                                                                                                                                                                              


-- Need difference between event_time of (id 42044) and event_time of (id 42045)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is the ordering defined? What if there is an odd number of rows?

Comment: we can order by event_id and event_time

Comment: ... but one of them ascending and the other one descending...

Comment: would have to de ascending so the next time stamp follows

Answer (score 1):

If you want `events` ordered by `event_time` for the calculation, you could first calculate the difference to the next row and then take every second row of the result:

```
SELECT id, prev_id, diff
FROM (SELECT id,
             lag(id) OVER w AS prev_id,
             lag(event_time) OVER w - event_time AS diff,
             row_number() OVER w
      FROM events
      WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY event_time DESC)
     ) q
WHERE row_number % 2 = 0;

  id   | prev_id |   diff   
-------+---------+----------
 42045 |   42044 | 00:03:08
 42042 |   42043 | 01:23:00
 42047 |   42046 | 00:00:14
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Danke, Laurenz. Du bist unglaublich!